# Bug between tasks and minipage and multicol and geometry?

Tags: minipage, multicol, geometry, tasks

I have noticed the following behaviour. I wonder if it is a bug or if it is normal.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tasks, lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\settasks{debug}

% Indents and inter-paragraph spaces
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.1cm}


\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\begin{tasks}(2)
\task $\sum_{k=3}^n 2(k+1)$ 
\task $\sum_{k=10}^{20} 3^{k+1}$ 
\task $\sum_{k=5}^{15} k(2k-1)$ 
\task $\sum_{k=3}^n \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$ 
\task $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{2}{5^{3k+2}}$ 
\task $\sum_{k=13}^{40} 3k(1-k)$ 
\task $\sum_{k=2}^{10} (-1)^k\times 3^{k+1}$ 
\task $\sum_{k=5}^{n-1} \frac{2^{k-1}}{5^{k+1}}$
\end{tasks}
\end{minipage}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In my document, even without the `0.97` I have the same strange behaviour.

Comment: Do you have any reason to use a `minipage`?

Comment: I want to avoid splitting an environment between two columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your task columns are bit to large for the minipage (by 0.24pt). A minipage calls at the begin the command `\sloppy` and this means that LaTeX will not let the second task stick out into the margin (and issue an overfull hbox message) but move it to the next line.

The task then moves into the margin as `tasks` does internally some horizontal shifting. The label actually sticks out to the left.

So either enlarge the columnwidth a bit, or add \fussy to the minipage:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tasks, lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\settasks{debug}

% Indents and inter-paragraph spaces
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.1cm}


\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
 \fussy
\begin{tasks}(2)
\task $\sum_{k=3}^n 2(k+1)$ 
\task $\sum_{k=10}^{20} 3^{k+1}$ 
\task $\sum_{k=5}^{15} k(2k-1)$ 
\task $\sum_{k=3}^n \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$ 
\task $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{2}{5^{3k+2}}$ 
\task $\sum_{k=13}^{40} 3k(1-k)$ 
\task $\sum_{k=2}^{10} (-1)^k\times 3^{k+1}$ 
\task $\sum_{k=5}^{n-1} \frac{2^{k-1}}{5^{k+1}}$
\end{tasks}
\end{minipage}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works. I still think there is something to be fixed in the `taks` package.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly it works with `column-sep=1em`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tasks, lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\settasks{debug,column-sep=1em}

%% Indents and inter-paragraph spaces
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.1cm}


\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{tasks}(2)
\task $\sum_{k=3}^n 2(k+1)$ 
\task $\sum_{k=10}^{20} 3^{k+1}$ 
\task $\sum_{k=5}^{15} k(2k-1)$ 
\task $\sum_{k=3}^n \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$ 
\task $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{2}{5^{3k+2}}$ 
\task $\sum_{k=13}^{40} 3k(1-k)$ 
\task $\sum_{k=2}^{10} (-1)^k\times 3^{k+1}$ 
\task $\sum_{k=5}^{n-1} \frac{2^{k-1}}{5^{k+1}}$
\end{tasks}
\end{minipage}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I finally found a MWE with the bug. It comes from `geometry`. See the edited question. Thanks

Comment: @Colas please see my edited answer

Comment: @Colas No, it isn't due to geometry, but apparently to wrong computations when two-column format is involved. The `minipage` does the rest.